# Convert list contain strings to two list with encoding

Tags: python

So i have a list for tic tac toe and I reacive the board like this

```
board=[' ', 'X', 'O', ' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ']
```

I would like to make to two variable for something in my mind
the first variable is the `O_variable` wich will contain all the o's in the list and replace them with 1 and should be like this `[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]`and the same for the x's `[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]` so try the following code

```
Bo_variable=O_variable=x_variable=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(len(board)):
    if board[i]=='O':
        O_variable[i]=1
    if boardt[i]=='X':
        x_variable[i]=1
```

but the outcome for both variable `O_variable` and `x_variable` is the same

```
[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]
```

what causes this?
Note : I don't to encode the list from the first i receive it like this

Answer (score 2):

Both `O_variable` and `x_variabl` reference to the same array, therefore changed altogether.

Define them in separate lines.

```
O_variable = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x_variabl  = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

As @yatu commented, this can be converted to the more resilient code:

```
BOARD_SIZE = 10
# Create a zeros array of size `BOARD_SIZE`
O_variable = [0] * BOARD_SIZE
# Copy `O_variable` zeroes array
x_variable = O_variable[:]
```

Comment: You might want to define those lists with somethings like `O_variable = [0 for _ in range(10)]; x_variable = O_variable[:]` instead @RAbeeq `O_variable[:]` copies the first list

Comment: Of course, that would be more resilient, and better. Just wanted to pass the point to the OP, anyway I'll update. Thank you @yatu

Comment: No worries @AvivYaniv :) Important here it for OP to understand the concept of a *copy*

Comment: Indeed @yatu! Updated :)

Answer (score 1):

This declaration means both your `O_variable` and `x_variable` are pointing to the same list.

```
Bo_variable=O_variable=x_variable=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

hence when you call `O_variable[i]=1` and `x_variable[i]=1` they're both modifying the same list. You need to separate `O_variable` and `x_variable`

```
O_variable=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x_variable=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

If you want a `Bo_varaible` list you can combine then after they are finished through the loop via

```
bo_variable = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(len(bo_variable)):
    if O_variable[i] == 1 or x_variable[i]==1:
        bo_variable[i] =1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of the first line. You initialized the 2 variables in a wrong way.

If you O_variable=x_variable=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], then the 2 variables uses a same memory, so either variable's change affects the other.

You should initialize the 2 variables separately like this.

```
x_variable = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
O_variable = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```